# Cannot get the TinyMCE.MVC.Jquery.Sample to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, tinymce, nuget-package

I have downloaded the `TinyMCE.MVC.Jquery` and `TinyMCE.MVC.Jquery.Sample` into a new MVC.NET 4 project, however I cannot seem to get it to show in the sample `TinyMCESampleJQuery` cshtml page.

I only changed the

```
content_css: "@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")",
```

to point to my stylesheet and added the jquery and tinymce references

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Do I need to do anything else to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I tried something and this worked!

I removed the jquery link from my tinymce cshtml, and moved the jquery scripts bundle in the layout page to the  and that worked

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing there stylesheet and have you added the required images into your project?

Comment: where do I reference their stylesheet?  I tried to reference it here :-             content_css : "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/default/content.css")",  but no luck.

Comment: Thariama - I cannot make comments at the moment on other peoples posts so I had to put it as an answer!